# NSString writeToFile losing Indentation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have an OSX application that creates Objective-C code. In other words, writes to two files, .h and .m.

To write to a file, I am using NSString writeToFile atomically true, encoding NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Although my two files are created with the text correctly, all formatting is lost. Everything ends up aligned to the left, even when imported into Xcode. Although I know I can select the text and indent it using ctrl + i, this is not the solution I want.

Now, when I copy the NSString to the clipboard, and paste it into Xcode, the formatting stays how it should.

Does anyone know a way where I can keep the text indentation the way it was in Xcode without having to write rules about how many curly braces are open? Here is some modified example code of what I am doing so far:

```
NSString *code = @"for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {\n";
code = [code stringByAppendingString:@"NSLog(@\"HelloWorld\");\n"];
code = [code stringByAppendingString:@"}\n"];

// If I run the two lines below, then my NSString is copied to the clipboard. When I paste into Xcode, formatting stays as it should.
[[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] clearContents];
[[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:code forType:NSStringPboardType];

// If I run the code below instead, then two files are created. But they do not keep the formatting.
NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
[panel setNameFieldStringValue:@"MyClass"];
[panel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        NSError *errorH = nil;
        NSError *errorM = nil;

        NSString *pathH = [[[panel URL] path] stringByAppendingString:@".h"];
        NSString *pathM = [[[panel URL] path] stringByAppendingString:@".m"];

        [code writeToFile:pathH atomically:true encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&errorH];
        [code writeToFile:pathM atomically:true encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&errorM];

        if (!errorH && !errorM) {
            NSLog(@"Success");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error Saving Files");
        }
    }
}];
```

EDIT: After not getting a clear way to do this elegantly, I simply had to write some of my own formatting code to mimic the formatting done by Xcode. It doesn't work 100% properly... for instance, when I am adding multiple items to an array using:

```
 @[@"string1",
    @"string2",
    @"string3"];\n
```

This doesn't stay properly indented to where the array began. And I'm sure there are other cases that my code doesn't handle. Not a huge deal though. If a solution comes to mind later, I can implement it. But for now, the formatting simply won't be as pretty as intended. Here is a method, and a helper method, that anyone can use to implement similar functionality (handles tabs and curly braces only)

```
- (NSString *) formatWithIdentationForExport : (NSString *) theString {
    NSString *s = @"";

    NSMutableArray *fileLines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[theString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] copyItems: YES];
    int numberOfCurlyBraces = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < fileLines.count; i++) {
        NSString *currentLine = fileLines[i];
        int numberOfOpenBracesInLine = [self getNumberOfOccurancesOf:@"{" inString:currentLine];
        int numberOfCloseBracesInLine = [self getNumberOfOccurancesOf:@"}" inString:currentLine];
        numberOfCurlyBraces -= numberOfCloseBracesInLine;

        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfCurlyBraces; j++) {
            currentLine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\t%@", currentLine];
        }
        currentLine = [currentLine stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
        s = [s stringByAppendingString:currentLine];

        numberOfCurlyBraces += numberOfOpenBracesInLine;
    }

    return s;
}

- (int) getNumberOfOccurancesOf : (NSString *) substring inString : (NSString *) str {
    int count = 0, length = (int)[str length];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);
    while(range.location != NSNotFound) {
        range = [str rangeOfString:substring options:0 range:range];
        if(range.location != NSNotFound) {
            range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
            count++; 
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: What is NSUTFStringEncoding?  Did you create it for yourself?

Comment: Whoops, I made a typo in that one. It is NSUTF8StringEncoding. I tried a few of the other encoding options, but none changed the formatting. But they made it so Xcode wouldn't color code my code anymore. So I stuck with NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Comment: Let us see what you have done in code.  I have programmatically generated an implementation file in the past.  The original formats stay.  So you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I added some modified code to show what I am doing. I have a feeling that the code generated is just plain code without any formatting. But when you paste in Xcode, Xcode formats accordingly. Maybe I'm wrong, but that's just my hunch so far.

Comment: NSWTFStringEncoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "\t" for an indent.  I won't do it for every line of your code, but do something like

```
[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {\n"];
[codeStr appendString:@"\t"];[codeStr appendString:@"NSLog(@\"center\");"];
```

Comment: Ya, I think I'm going to have to add the \t based on every curly brace that is open. Since it's my own code being generated, I won't have to worry about those being within comments or anything. When final code is generated, I'll simply have to go through each line one at a time, look how many curly braces there are, and add or subtract from the total. Then insert \t for the number of curly braces there currently are open for that line. That way my paste code will still work the same without extra \ts being inserted, and the export code will be formatted hopefully correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When you generate your ObjC code, you should manually add indentation (tabs or spaces) into it, otherwise it will not be saved to file.